# Flutter show values from JSON array and on tap change the index

Tags: flutter

I am a newbie in a flutter. I have a simple app I need to show the JSON value in my container and on tap, the second value will show.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List _questions = [
    {'would': 'Coffe', 'rather': 'Tea'},
    {'would': 'Coffe', 'rather': 'Tea'},
    {'would': 'Coffe', 'rather': 'Tea'},
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PrimaryColor = const Color(0xff404040);

    final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        'Would you Rather',
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'FredokaOne'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
    );

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff404040),
        appBar: appBar,
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => print("And after click here it will change both question"),
              child: Container(
                child: Text(_questions[0].would,),

              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => print("And after click here it will change both question"),
              child: Container(
                child: Text(_questions[0].rather,),

              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Here I have a list of questions. In 1 array there are 2 values. I need to show these 2 values in each container and when I tap on the container the next array will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable `index` that will increment in `nextQuestion` function is triggered when one of the containers is tapped. The increment will stop once it reaches the last element of `_questions` List. Finally, use the index when assigning the values of the `Text` inside the Containers to change when changing the `index`.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List _questions = [
    {'would': 'Coffe', 'rather': 'Tea'},
    {'would': 'Blue', 'rather': 'Red'},
    {'would': 'Green', 'rather': 'Yellow'},
  ];
  int index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PrimaryColor = const Color(0xff404040);
    int size = _questions.length;

    void nextQuestion(){
      if(index < size - 1)
      setState(() {
        index++;
      });
      print(index);
    }

    final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        'Would you Rather',
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'FredokaOne'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
    );

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff404040),
        appBar: appBar,
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              onTap: nextQuestion,
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                child: Text(_questions[index]['would']),
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: nextQuestion,
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                child: Text(_questions[index]['rather']),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```